# reading json file python

Tags: python, dictionary

```
js = {"Alex":{"b_":{"ep_0":"[1,2,3]"}, "g_":{"ep_0":"[3,4,5]"}, "f_":{"ep_0":"[3,4,5]", "ep_1":"[3,4,5]"}},
      "Sam":{"b_":{"ep_0":"[1,2,3]"}, "g_":{"ep_0":"[3,4,5]"}},
      "Joe":{"b_":{"ep_0":"[1,2,3]"}, "g_":{"ep_0":"[3,4,5]"}, "f_":{"ep_1":"[31,44,56]"}}
      }
```

I need to read ep_0 and ep_1 for each user, here is my snipped code:

```
users = [i for i in js.keys()]
data = {}
final_data = {}
for key in users:
        for user in js[key].keys():
            if 'f_' not in key:
                continue
            for z in js[users]['f_']:
                if 'ep_0' not in z:
                    continue
                data['ep0'] = js[user]['f_']['ep_0']
                if 'ep_1' not in z:
                    continue
                data['ep1'] = js[user]['f_']['ep_1']
                final_data[user] = data

    print(final_data)
```

the output of my code is {} and desire output should be:

```
{'Alex': {'f_':{'ep_0':'[3,4,5]', 'ep_1':'[3,4,5]'}}, 'Joe': { 'f_':{'ep_1':'[31,44,56]'}} }
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: can you show the expected output?

Comment: use `print()` in different places to see values in variables - this helps you to see where is the problem.

Comment: Learn to use `.items()`.

Comment: Nothing you're showing here is JSON. Your `js = ...` is assigning a Python data structure; to be JSON, it would need to have double quotes -- unless you're referring to the lists in the inner strings being JSON?

Comment: Neither is it a file.

Comment: Step-by-step debugging should make the problem clear. Set a breakpoint at the line `if 'f_' not in key:`, look at what the value of `key` is, and think about whether that value, *itself*, contains `f_`.

Comment: See this lovely [debug](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) blog for help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is my simple solution to your problem.

```
final_data = {}
for user in js.keys():
    if 'f_' not in js[user]:
        continue
    final_data[user] = { "f_": js[user]['f_']}

print(final_data)
```

Output

```
{'Alex': {'f_': {'ep_0': '[3,4,5]', 'ep_1': '[3,4,5]'}}, 'Joe': {'f_': {'ep_1': '[31,44,56]'}}}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that your most glaring problem is

```
users = [i for i in js.keys()]
...
        for z in js[users]['f_']:
```

`users` is a poorly-formed list of the keys in your dict.  Just what do you expect `js[users]` to mean?

However, your *first* problem is the combination

```
for key in users:
    for user in js[key].keys():
        if 'f_' not in key:
```

`users` is the list of names: Alex, Sam, Joe.  How do you expect to find `f_` in that list?  You've incorrectly connected your variables.

---

I strongly recommend that you start over with your coding.  Employ *incremental programming*.  Write a couple of lines that do *one* step of your process.  Insert `print` statements to test that they do what you expect.  Only *after* you've proved that, do you add more lines.

The problem you're facing here is that you wrote too much code at once, making several mistakes, and you're now in a situation where a single fix cannot get you any reasonable output.

Been there, done that, and I have all too many t-shirts from my forays into my own creations.

Answer (score 0):

I'm seeing `js[users]` in a few places in your code. You probably mean `js[user]`, since `users` is just the list of keys from `js`, not a key itself. Try fixing that and see if it helps you.

Comment: Thank you for mentioning it (it was correct in my code and I edited my question as well). I can get the ep_0 if I remove the condition of ep_1.